# Oracle RegEx in a Cast Procedure

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-replace

I have a Cast Procedure for a table with "raw" data.  Any time a record comes from any of our locations into the raw table, my procedure "cleans" the data and loads it into a new table.  The original raw table is all varchars and my procedure converts date and number fields to the proper data types.  From the clean table, a Java program selects any new records on a daily basis and FTPs them off in a file to another dept.  Have just learned that a few of the fields accept input from users and on a rare occasion, someone uses a pipe in what they input.  A pipe symbol happens to be the delimiter that the other dept is using and whenever a pipe shows up in the middle of a field, it throws a wrench on their end.

I've never used REGEX or REGEXP_REPLACE in Oracle before.  There are only three fields where the users can input data - MISTINTCOMMENT, PALETTE, COLORID.  How do I use REGEX or REGEXP_REPLACE to replace any pipes with a space?  Do I want to do it on each field?  Or is this something I should "wrap around" the entire statement (in case there's a field I missed where someone might be able to input a pipe)?

Here is the portion of the procedure where the Values are cleaned and inserted into new table.  How to best use RegEx with this?

```
VALUES (CASE 
        WHEN THECOSTCENTER IS NOT NULL
            THEN THECOSTCENTER
            ELSE (SUBSTR(TRIM(THESENDING_QMGR), -6))
            END, 
        CASE    
        WHEN THESTORENBR = '0' AND (SUBSTR(THESENDING_QMGR, 1, 5) = 'PDPOS')
            THEN TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(THESENDING_QMGR, 8, 4))
        WHEN THESTORENBR = '0' AND (SUBSTR(THESENDING_QMGR, 1, 8) = 'PROD_POS')
            THEN TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(THESENDING_QMGR, 9, 4))
            ELSE TO_NUMBER(NVL(THESTORENBR,'0')) 
        END, 
        TO_NUMBER(NVL(THECONTROLNBR,'0')), TO_NUMBER(NVL(THELINENBR,'0')), THESALESNBR, TO_NUMBER(NVL(THEQTYMISTINT,'0')), THEREASONCODE, THEMISTINTCOMMENT, 
        THESIZECODE, THETINTERMODEL, THETINTERSERIALNBR, TO_NUMBER(NVL(THEEMPNBR,'0')), TO_DATE(THETRANDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD'), THETRANTIME, THECDSADLFLD, 
        THEPRODNBR, THEPALETTE, THECOLORID, TO_DATE(THEINITTRANDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_NUMBER(NVL(THEGALLONSMISTINTED,'0'),'999999999.99'), THEUPDATEEMPNBR, 
        TO_DATE(THEUPDATETRANDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_NUMBER(NVL(THEGALLONS,'0'),'999999999.99'), THEFORMSOURCE, THEUPDATETRANTIME, THESOURCEIND, 
        TO_DATE(THECANCELDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD'), THECOLORTYPE, TO_NUMBER(NVL(THECANCELEMPNBR,'0')), TO_BOOLEAN(THENEEDEXTRACTED), TO_BOOLEAN(THEMISTINTMQXTR), 
        THEDATASOURCE, THETRANGUID, TO_NUMBER(NVL(THETERMNBR,'0')), TO_NUMBER(NVL(THETRANNBR,'0')), TO_NUMBER(NVL(THETRANID,'0')), THEID, THETINTABLESALESNBR,
        TO_NUMBER(NVL(THERETURNQTY,'0')), THECREATED_TS, THEXMIT_GUID, THESENDING_QMGR, THEMSG_ID, THEPUT_TS, 
        THEBROKER_NAME, THECHECKSUM);
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd need a regular expression.  Why not a simple `replace`, i.e. `replace( your_expression, '|', ' ' )`.

Comment: Why do you want to use regular expressions, rather than [a simple `replace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/REPLACE.html#GUID-1A79BDDF-2D3B-4AD4-98E7-985B2E59DA6B)? It seems like you should only apply that to the columns you know might have user input. Alternatively, can the downstream system handle pipes in quoted values?

Comment: Didn't know there was a "replace" (I learn something new every day!) And no, the downstream system wants pipes replaced with the space.  Let me test REPLACE!  Thank you.

Comment: REPLACE worked for my needs.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use a [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm) to replace pipes, escape them:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(x, '\|', ' ')
```

This is useful to know when your more complex expressions include a pipe.

In this case, [`REPLACE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions134.htm) that performs literal text search and replace will suffice:

```
REPLACE(x, '|', ' ')
```